# Import 12000 files into one table

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, apache-flink

I need to setup a streaming enviroment for my project. 
The dataset is next: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/152883/User_guide_T-drive.pdf

I'm planning to use PostgreSQL and Apache Kafka as a source and then connect to Kafka with Apache Spark or Flink, however the problem is that the dataset is around 10 000 text files.

So, the question is what is most efficient/elegant way to import ~10000 files (each around 500 rows) into one table.

For now I've tried python script with **psycopg2** and **executemany** method (super slow) and **Apache FLink Job with JDBC connector** (good speed, but don't know how to iterate over 10000 files in one Job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to read the folder using spark and open an odbc connection per partition and iterate and write each row.

Comment: This worked quite smooth with paralellism 4, however I've used Flink.